# Static array as a private member

Tags: c++, arrays, class

In such form...

```
#ifndef UNICODE
#define UNICODE 
#endif


#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
    void makeFoo(TCHAR* output)
    {
        wcscpy(outputBuffer,TEXT("Hello world ♥"));
    }
private:
    static const int MAX_OUTPUT_SIZE=2000;  
    static TCHAR outputBuffer[MAX_OUTPUT_SIZE];
};


int main()
{
    TCHAR string[255];

    A example;

    example.makeFoo(string);

    MessageBox(0,string,0,0);

    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}
```

... we have a
linking error!

> 1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private:
>   static wchar_t * A::outputBuffer" (?outputBuffer@A@@0PA_WA)

Comment: Your question indicates that you don't have a strong understanding of how the `static` keyword works, or what it does.  Are you sure you want this to be `static`?  That means there is only one instance of `A::outputBuffer` shared by all instances of class `A`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The linker error occurs because you have not provided a definition for the `A::outputBuffer` anywhere. Fix this by writing this in file scope:

```
TCHAR A::outputBuffer[A::MAX_OUTPUT_SIZE];
```

The value of `string` is unexpected because that buffer is uninitialized; `makeFoo` does nothing with its argument, and you do not initialize the buffer manually. Therefore it can contain anything at all ("garbage").

Comment: That is a *definition* for `outputBuffer`. *Initializer* has nothing to do with the linker error.

Comment: @AndreyT: Of course. Meddling too much with other languages lately. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
TCHAR A::outputBuffer[A::MAX_OUTPUT_SIZE];
```

above `main()`.